# Check list to see if element greater than specified number

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to check if a specific element in the list is greater than a set value.

So

```
x=22
list=[10,20,30] 

# check if anything in list is greater than x
# do something to the list
```

I'm just not sure what commands to use in this scenario to check every list element or if it's even possible in one line.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Unfortunately, it's not clear what you want. Please clarify: Do you just want to know if the list contains an element greater than the given value? Or a list of all elements greater? Or if a specific element (say the 3rd element out of 5) is greater?

Answer (score 20):

Use [`any`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any), Python's natural way of checking if a condition holds for, well, *any* out of many:

```
x = 22 
lst = [10, 20, 30]  # do NOT use list as a variable anme

if any(y > x for y in lst):
    # do stuff with lst
```

`any` will terminate upon the first truthy element of the iterable it is passed and, thus, not perform any spurious iterations which makes it preferable to `max` or list comprehension based approaches that have to always iterate the entire list. Asymptotically however, its time complexity is, of course, still linear.

Also, you should not shadow built-in names like `list`.

Answer (score 4):

You ask for "if *any* element in the list is greater than `x`". If you just want one element, you could just find the greatest element in the list using the `max()` function, and check if it's larger than `x`:

```
if max(list) > x:
    ...
```

There's also a one-liner you can do to make a list of *all* elements in the list greater than `x`, using *list comprehensions* ([here's a tutorial, if you want one](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/list-comprehensions-in-python)):

```
>>> x = 22
>>> list = [10, 20, 30, 40]
>>> greater = [i for i in list if i > x]
>>> print(greater)
[30, 40]
```

This code generates a list `greater` of all the elements in `list` that are greater than `x`. You can see the code responsible for this:

```
[i for i in list if i > x]
```

This means, "Iterate over `list` and, if the condition `i > x` is true for any element `i`, add that element to a new list. At the end, return that new list."

Answer (score 1):

You could use `filter` and filter your list for items greater than `22`, if 
the `len` of this filtered list is `> 0` that means your original list contains a value larger than `22`

```
n = 22
lst = [10,20,30]

if len(list(filter(lambda x: x > n, lst))) > 0:
    # do something to lst
```

Answer (score 0):

List comprehension would suit your use case.

```
In [1]: x=22

In [2]: l=[10,20,30]

In [3]: exist = [n for n in l if n > x]

In [4]: if exist:
   ...:     print "elements {} are greater than x".format(exist)
   ...: 
elements [30] are greater than x
```

If your list is very long, use generator so that you do not have to iterate through all elements of the list.

```
In [5]: exist = next(n for n in l if n > x)

In [6]: if exist:                          
    print "Element {} is greater than x".format(exist)
   ...:     
Element 30 is greater than x
```